# помогите допилить метод половинного деления

Tags: python, функции, численные-методы

есть написанный код для метода половинного деления

```
def biss(func, bounds, eps=1e-5):
    a, b = bounds
    if func(a) * func(b) > 0:
        print('На заданном интервале нет корней')
        exit(0)
    x0 = (a + b) / 2
    while abs(a - b) >= eps:
        if func(a) * func(x0) > 0:
            a = x0
        else:
            b = x0
        x0 = (a + b) / 2
    return x0


def func(x):
    return math.sin(x)  # math.sin(x) (-1, 3), -x ** 2 + 4 (-1, 5), math.exp(x) - 6 * x - 3


x = biss(func, (-1, 3))

print('Полученный х = ', x, '\n', 'Значение функции в найденной точке: ', func(x), '\n')
```

НО, он не работает для функции x**2, т.е. с параболами у которых вершина на оси Ох (говорили можно сделать через производные, локальные мин/макс искать, но для этого нужно найти пересечения с осью Ох, с чем и была проблемы в предыдущем вопросе) и находит только один х, подскажите как можно исправить. Может есть идеи как по другому сделать с параболой.

Comment: этим методом вы не найдете, просто в силу его определения - знак функции на границах должен быть противоположен. Да и если  на интервале несколько корней - тоже не выйдет. Так что допиливать нечего, он делает то, что обещал

Comment: а по заданию нам говорят надо допилить чтобы работало :/ хотя тоже удивляюсь как, если по определению знаки f(a) и f(b) должны быть разными

Comment: надо использовать другие методы, градиентный спуск, или что-то подобное. Тот же ньютон на параболе должен работать

Comment: Вам нужна именно `x^2`? Или всё-таки `-x^2 + 4`?

Answer (score 0):

Так как значения функций, в таком случае, одного знака мы не можем использовать произведения для определения с какой стороны переносить границу для приближения к корню. Но мы можем определить на какой ветке находиться x0, слева или справа от корня. Если abs(func(x0)) > abs(func(x0 + eps)), то слева.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import math


def biss(func, bounds, eps=1e-5):
    a, b = bounds
    x0 = (a + b) / 2
    if func(a) * func(b) > 0:
        while abs(a - b) >= eps:
            if abs(func(x0)) > abs(func(x0 + eps)):
                a = x0
            else:
                b = x0
            x0 = (a + b) / 2
        return x0
    else:
        while abs(a - b) >= eps:
            if func(a) * func(x0) > 0:
                a = x0
            else:
                b = x0
            x0 = (a + b) / 2
        return x0


def func(x):
    return -(x - 2) ** 2


x = biss(func, (-1, 5))

print('Полученный х = ', x, 'Значение функции в найденной точке: ', func(x))

Полученный х =  1.9999971389770508 Значение функции в найденной точке:  -8.185452315956354e-12
```

Абсолютные значения функций нужны для отрицательных функций.